# Socket.io with the rest API

Tags: php, node.js, sockets

I have one quite old app but we have php API for our chat function that has two main functions: get last 20 messages and insert the new message into the database.

Currently, we are using AJAX for updating the data, but I'll like to update data quicker.

Is it possible to connect socket.io to some php API? I tried to search something on this topic but there are no good examples of it. Can you give me please little push how I can achieve something like this?

- users are connected to nodejs server which returns json with the messages
- when new user add the message, nodejs server call API for adding a new message to a database and after that it triggers "new message" event
- when the event "new message" is listened by the nodejs server, it fetches data from the database, format it to the json and triggers event "data updated"
- when other users listen to the event "data updated", they just get a new list of messages in the json

My idea is that this would work similarly as some cache layer because the data from the database will be fetched only once (by the triggered event) and then served to the users as static json.

Thanks for any help with this.

Note: I need to use the old php api because of some special functions in chat formatting that is processed on the server. It's not possible to rewrite it from scratch. I just want to use socket.io for pushing data to users from the server when there are some new data. Now they call for a new data with ajax even if there are no new messages and that, of course, creates unnecessary db connections, etc.

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets shouldn't be way faster than AJAX but what you are describing is the correct way to implement this. NodeJS is more than capable to send HTTP requests to another server ( in your case php ). Check the documentation here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback
or use this request module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request for simpler code.

Don't forget that what you are doing required your restAPI to respond back with HTTP prior to sending success info back to the client using websocket. This means that your performance gains won't really be that great.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why do you think it won't improve performance? My idea is that every client is downloading static data, and only when there are new messages, node server connects to php rest api, fetch them and then serve to all the clients. In that case, it's not important if there are 1000 or 2000 clients because fetching data from the database is done only once (when there is a new message). But maybe I am missing something or my idea is too idealistic...

Comment: I just did not understand your concept very well. What you are describing now should yield better performance since if that was done only from HTTP there would be requirements for 1000 or 2000 unique http requests and all of them would require the headers to fly from the server to the client so yeah I believe your idea is fine.